# iostat ( column svctm is not trusted any more ) what to use instead?

Tags: devices, disk, iostat

I'm running a Linux Server with "Oracle Linux Server release 6.5" which is pretty much the same as RedHat Version.

I need to determine the latency on my disk devices.

The man page of the iostat command states :

```
svctm
    The  average  service  time (in milliseconds) for I/O requests that were 
    issued to the device. Warning! Do not trust this field any more. This field
    will be removed in a future sysstat version.
```

What is recommended to be used instead on this version?
The Kernel version is: 3.8.13-16.2.1.el6uek.x86_64

I understand that the counters in this Kernel version are not reliable so the developers seemed to not trust the numbers any more. But what can be used instead of the `iostat`? ( `/proc/diskstats`? )